# Using HTTP_HOST to identify the identify the previous host name

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite

I have changed my Domain name of my site test.com to test2.com

Domain name changed from `test.com to test2.com`

```
I want to know if all the pages like test.com/* will be redirected to test2.com/*
```

In test2.com, I am writing the rewrite rule in mod_rewrite to identify the smart mobile device.

```
For all smart phone I would like to redirect requests test.com/* to test2.com (home page)

For every non smart phone I would like to redirect test.com/* to test2.com/*
```

I have researched the following condition for this. I am not sure if this is correct or not.

I have tried some thing like this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.com$ [AND]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} mobile
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|windows phone) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://test2.com/mobil/#1 [L]
```

Comment: _"For all smart phone I would like to redirect requests test.com/* to test2.com (home page)"_ - **WHY?**. I bloody hate it when sites redirect me from a deep link (found from a forum link or search engine) to their mobile home page. I directly leave those sites and never return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your  `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# For mobile devices:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?test\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|windows phone) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://test2.com/ [L,R=301]

# For non-mobile devices:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?test\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://test2.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Superb answer. Thank you.

Comment: I will be writing this in test2.com servers only right. In that case do I need mention the complete web site name in rewrite rule.

Comment: You will be writing this in `test.com` `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess`

Comment: actually I will be shutting down the test.com servers and need to write it in test2.com. can you help me with that

Comment: Even if you shutdown `test.com` host you still own that domain. Just point its A record to the same host as host where `test2.com` is pointed to. Once that is done put above code in `test2.com DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess`

Comment: Thank you. I am really new here. Can you tell me what is A record. Can we point it to host2.com while changing the DNS.

Comment: A record is basically IP address of the host where `test.com` will be pointed to. As an alternative to my previous comment you can even use CNAME (alias) of `test2.com` as `test.com`.

Comment: In the rewrite rule, you have mentioned the complete site address as http://test2.com. As I am writing these rules in test2.com only now, is it necessary to give the complete address again. Or can we mention teh relative path. Please confirm.

Comment: I had to use full address because we were dealing with 2 domains and external redirect from one domain to another.

Comment: Thank you. I hope it will create any problems if I place in test2.com server.

Comment: Right as I commented earlier when `test.com` is pointed to `test2.com` (using A or CNAME) then above rule will work just fine.