# Redirect any page coming from different host

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am writing a rewrite condition to redirect any page that is coming from host abc.com to my website home page.

My site name `mysite.com` and I want to write rewrite rule there.

**Redirect abc.com/* to my home page**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?test\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://mysite.com/ [L,R=301]
#I doubt how to redirect it to my current website home page
```

I also want to redirect any page coming from `cdf.com` to `/cdf/*`

**Redirect cdf.com/* to /cdf/***

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?cdf\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /cdf/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Please help me with correct rewrite rule?

I doubt if I have to mention complete site address.

Comment: So what's your question? Are the rules not working? How are they not working?

Comment: @JonLin. I have not yet kept these rules yet. I have to place these rules directly in production. Hence, I would like to check the correctness before I proceed.

Comment: @Patan: Please try explaining your questions again as its not very clear what you're looking for.

Comment: @anubhava. My current website is mysite.com. I want to know if we can give the current website address directly in rewrite rule or do we have to give relative address.

Comment: @Patan: You don't need to put your current site's address in those rules unless you have more than one site addresses pointing to same DOCUMENT_ROOT.

Comment: @anubhava. Thank you. How do I rewrite this if I want to redirect to my home page. RewriteRule ^ http://mysite.com/

Comment: That will be `RewriteRule ^redirect-this/?$ / [L,R]`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38076/discussion-between-patan-and-anubhava)

Comment: I am actually using my mobile at present. Please let me know if you a specific question and I will respond once I am near my computer.

Comment: @anubhava. Thanks. yesterday as answer to my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19005471/using-http-host-to-identify-the-identify-the-previous-host-name . you have mentioned the complete webAddress in the rewrite rule. Is it valid or do we have to mention the relative path there.